# Reference Request for Minkowski (?) Theorem proof.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm looking for a statement, I believe to be due to Minkowski, that says something along the lines of:

"For an algebraic number field, $K$, $\exists$ only finitely many prime integers, $p\in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $p$ is ramified in $K$.

To put this in context, I am writing a project with a few chapters on the *Kronecker-Weber Theorem*, and the final step in the reduction of the case to a field where $p$ is the only ramified prime needs this statement.

I am sure that it's true, but I can't remember the exact theorem/proposition, and if anyone could direct me to a proof that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Recall that a prime ramifies if and only if it divides the discriminant. Since there are only finitely many primes dividing the discriminant, you are done.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks, that'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minkowski did many things, but I think you might be getting mixed up with the [Hermite-Minkowski theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem) which says that there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of number fields with discriminant less than a given number.

As for the theorem you're referring to, I don't know for sure who it is due to, but here is a general form of it from Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*, p.49:

> [image]

For your reference, here is 8.3:

> [image]

Alternatively, here is the approach taken in Marcus' *Number Fields*, p.72-73:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for that, I actually have a copy of Number Fields sitting on my desk, so that's a little embarrassing :)